# WinSock...и еще 12 символов

Tags: c++builder, winsock, c++, сокет

Программа компилируется, но не происходит соединение с сервером. Почему это может быть? Какие у меня ошибки?
WSAGetLastError() выдает ошибку 0. Может, что то внешнее ее не пускает? Типа ативируса или фаервола.

```
 WSADATA ws;
 hostent* hn;
 char buff [4096];
 if (FAILED (WSAStartup (MAKEWORD( 2, 2 ), &ws) ) )
 { ListBox1->Items->Add("Библиотека WSAStartup не загружена."); }
 else
 { ListBox1->Items->Add("Библиотека WSAStartup загружена."); }
 SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);

if (s==INVALID_SOCKET)
 { ListBox1->Items->Add("Ошибка сокета."); }
 else
 { ListBox1->Items->Add("Сокет создан успешно."); }
 struct sockaddr_in adr;
 hn=gethostbyname("www.google.com");
 if (NULL==hn)
 { ListBox1->Items->Add("Ошибка получения адреса www.google.com."); }
 else
 { ListBox1->Items->Add("Адресс www.google.com получен."); }
 //заполнение структуры с адресом
 adr.sin_family = AF_INET;
 //adr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr=*(DWORD*)hn;
 adr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr=inet_addr("www.google.com");
 adr.sin_port = htons (80);
 //ListBox1->Items->Add(adr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr);
 if (SOCKET_ERROR==connect(s,(sockaddr*)&adr,sizeof(adr)))
 { ListBox1->Items->Add("Ошибка соединения."); }
 else
 { ListBox1->Items->Add("Соединение установлено."); }
 DWORD dwError=WSAGetLastError();
 ListBox1->Items->Add(dwError);
 closesocket(s);
 ListBox1->Items->Add("Сокет закрыт.");
 WSACleanup();
 ListBox1->Items->Add("Библиотека WSAStartup выгружена.");
```

C++Builder 6 (10.155)
Исходники: http://zalil.ru/30969595

**UPD:**

Когда я пишу:

```
adr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr=inet_addr(74.125.79.147);
```

У меня компилятор возмущается:

> [C++ Error] Unit1.cpp(44): E2223 Too many decimal points
>
> [C++ Error] Unit1.cpp(44): E2223 Too many decimal points
>
> [C++ Error] Unit1.cpp(44): E2110 Incompatible type conversion

Функция *connect* возвращает SOCKET_ERROR и не коннектится. Может быть я ему что-то неправильно задал?

Comment: А как вы поняли, что соединения не происходит? Что возвращает connect(s,(sockaddr*)&adr,sizeof(adr))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> adr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr=inet_addr("www.google.com");

пропиши тут IP адрес "74.125.79.147" ну или тот который пропингуеш сам

```
HOSTENT*    hosten; 
hosten= gethostbyname( name ); 
sa.sin_addr.s_addr = ((in_addr*)hosten->h_addr_list[0])->s_addr;
```

и как-то можно вытянуть адрес получаемый функцией gethostbyname

Comment: IP адрес возьмите в кавычки "74.125.79.147"